# Norm Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $C[0,1]$ is the set of continuous functions which map $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Define $C_{max}=(C[0,1],\|.\|_{\infty})$ and $C_{int}=(C[0,1],\|.\|_{1})$ where $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{t \in [0,1]}{|f(t)|}$ and $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1{|f(t)|}dt$. I want to show that the function $I:C_{max} \rightarrow C_{int}$ given by $I(f)=f$ is bijective, continuous but $I^{-1}$ is not continous.

Clearly $I$ is bijective from the definition of $I$. Now I want to show $I$ is continuous. Let $U \subset C_{int}$ be an open set. Note that $I^{-1}(U)=U$. Hence, if $B_{\|\|_{\infty}}(f,\frac{\epsilon}{n}) \subset B_{\|\|_1}(f,\epsilon)=U$ for all $f \in C[0,1]$, then $I$ is continuous.

Here I suspect the inequality $\int_0^1{|f(t)-g(t)|}dt \leq n \sup_{t \in [0,1]}{|f(t)-g(t)|}$ so that the inclusion above holds. But I don't know whether the inequality is correct or not. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If $\lvert f(t)\rvert \leqslant C$ for all $t$, what follows for $\int_0^1 \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt$?

Comment: You might note that $I$ is linear (which means continuity at the origin is all you need; alternatively, boundedness suffices as well). More importantly, note that injectiveness isn't quite as clear cut as you make it sound, as elements of $C_{\mathrm{int}}$ are actually equivalency classes. Continuity is important here.

Comment: @DanielFischer: We get $\int_0^1{|f(t)|}dt \leq C$ for all $t$

Comment: @JonathanY.: why $C_{int}$ is a set of equivalence classes?

Comment: @Idonknow: Well, it isn't really, but the $\|\cdot\|_1$ isn't a norm unless the zero function is the only one of size zero (which is the case here, but merits mentioning). Put differently, we have to note that if $f,g$ are two distinct continuous functions, then $\int|f-g|>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $f \in C_\max$ we have
$$
\|I(f)\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|\,dt\le \int_0^1\max_{[0,1]}|f|\,dt=\|f\|_\infty.
$$
This shows that $I: C_\max \to C_{\text{int}}$ is continuous.

Now take the sequence $f_n(t)=t^n$ in $C_{\text{int}}$. We have
$$
\|f_n\|_1=\int_0^1t^n\,dt=\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty,
$$
i.e. $f_n\to f\equiv 0$ in $C_{\text{int}}$, but
$$
\|f_n-f\|_\infty=\|f_n\|_\infty=1 \not\to 0.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_nI^{-1}(f_n)\ne I^{-1}(0)=0,
$$
i.e. $I^{-1}$ is not continuous.